# Load data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to do something like this:

HTML

```
<select id="firstSelect">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

Java Script

```
$(function () {

        $('#firstSelect').click(function () {

            $.getJSON("someService", function (data) {
                var options = '<option value="">Choose...</option>';
                $.each(data, function (index, order) {
                    options += "<option value='" + order.id + "'>" + order.title + "</option>";
                });
                $('#firstSelect').html(options);
            });
        });
}
```

The problem is when I first click on the select field, it doesn't fill with data from JSON, but when I clicked the 2nd time it appears and it fills in all the options.

Comment: What happens if you use `$("#firstSelect").append(options);`?

Comment: The same happens, except that after each opening of the select field duplicate data

Comment: Makes sense, I don't understand why it wouldn't work on the first click.  I mean there may be a slight delay from the server.

Comment: like @KevinBowersox said, I thought there may be a delay from server on the first call, you can prevent user from show the option before it loaded or the preferred way is to load the lookupdata at page load and when you click the option, just show the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to load content for the select field each time somebody clicks it ?
May be it would be better if you load it on page load ? So it will solve your "works just on second click" issue. And btw you don't need to fill select field by your own.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("someService", function (data) {
       var options = '<option value="">Choose...</option>';
       $.each(data, function (index, order) {
          options += "<option value='" + order.id + "'>" + order.title + "</option>";
            });
       $('#firstSelect').html(options);
    });        
})
```

Comment: This works good. I just wondered if this is a good solution when I have big data

Comment: If you have big data, like thousand categories, million subcategories for one of them and ten for all others - you should use separate json files and load them on click, depending on category. Smth like http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/qS3Tu/ It's just for adding subcat and it's very abstract.